# OGC filters not working on WFS service

Tags: qgis, wfs, ogc, ows

OGC filters not working on WFS service It only seems to serve up unfiltered data or a layer with a attributes table but no features as if nothing met the criteria. I have tried repeatedly with criteria that I know is in the dataset. Am I doing something wrong here? 
Using Qgis 2.14.11 built in WFS client

```
http://openmaps.gov.bc.ca/geo/ows?version=1.3.0&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=pub:WH SE_FOREST_VEGETATION.VEG_COMP_LYR_R1_POLY&SRSNAME=EPSG:3005&FILTER= <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
 <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
  <ogc:PropertyName>MAP_ID</ogc:PropertyName>
  <ogc:Literal>082M099</ogc:Literal>
 </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
</ogc:Filter>
```

When I run it with the filter removed from the URL, back to the CRS (EPSG:3005) it works but I usually run into a download limit long before getting the features I am after. If I run it with different criteria it works at it for what seems to be a appropriate amount of time considering the amount of data that It "should" be returning but no features. having the same problem with different datasets served up here.  I am suspecting that either the server just will not serve filtered data or the method I need to use is completely different somehow.

Comment: Can you upgrade to the latest shiny QGIS 3.4 and test. People are more likely going to help you out if you using this new version as 2.14 is no longer being supported and hence people cannot test your problem

Comment: are you encoding the URL?

Comment: I don't think so that is the properties > general> layer source field contents .I tried it I a browser and it again returns data without the filter but with with the filter it returns a error about missing style sheets.

Comment: @kartoza-geek I guess that will be the next thing I try to sort out . For some reason 2.14 is what I get after adding the repository and updating.

Comment: You have two version parameters in your request, 'version=1.3.0' is incorrect for WFS.

Comment: The [WFS 1.0.0 service](http://openmaps.gov.bc.ca/geo/ows?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities) doesn't support, `PropertyIsEqualTo`